# How to check whether a pointer is NULL before allocating more memory space?

Tags: c++

I'm using abstract factory design pattern for my project.

```
CPattern * CObjectA::Create(void)
{
    CPattern *p = new CPattern;
    patternList.push_back (p);
    return *p;
}

//Member variable
CPattern *pat = NULL;

pat = Obj.Create();
```

CObjectA will delete the space allocated during destructor. The problem is, if client do this again:

```
pat = Obj.Create();
```

I would have allocated another space and pat points to it. If this is called a few hundred times, I will keep on creating space without disallocating it.

Is there a way to check whether pat is empty before I allocate another space for it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You say that the CObjectA class destructor handles the freeing of space--why do you then say it will not be freed up if called a few hundred times?  Are there mutual exclusion concerns?  Or, is the question related to what will happen if you call the Obj.Create() function multiple times before a destructor is ever invoked?

Comment: Really sorry as I forgot to elaborate. I'm maintaining CObjectA. Clients are allowed to freely call Create() but my concern is that if pointer pat is a member variable of their class and since my destructor is only called when their app ends, the memory space I allocate will only be freed then. So, by design flaw, client call Create() and keep on assigning to member pat again and again, I want to control so that I don't allocate if pat is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete pat;
pat = Obj.Create();
```

A better solution would be to make `pat` a smart pointer, which will automatically delete the object when you reassign to a new object.

Keeping `patternList` up to date is another problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Your code's not consistent: the `Create` function returns a reference but should return a pointer (as implied by your later `pat = Obj.Create();`).  (Factories naturally return pointers rather than by-reference, as the latter encourages accidental copying into a local variable of the base type - something called slicing, where the data members specific to the actual run-time type aren't copied)

"CObjectA will delete the space allocated during destructor" - true, but for heap-allocated objects you have to `delete` them to trigger the destructor.  The "client" should check and `delete` before replacing `pat`:

```
delete pat;  // does nothing if pat's already NULL...
pat = new CObjectA.Create();
```

Comment: Is there a way to counter the problem where client don't call delete before calling Create()? Is there a way to know from the inside of CObjectA?

Comment: Well, looking closer - you're also coding `patternList.push_back(p);` and that pointer will be invalidated by the `delete`, which suggests the code's likely to try to use it afterwards and crash. As Mark suggests, returning a smart pointer's a better bet: it encourages the caller to use a smart pointer too, which can manage the deletion when updated with a new value. Further, good smart pointer libraries include weak pointers, which might be what you want in your patterns list: they report whether they still point to a valid object.